# How to set an item with two left icons in a List from a .kv file?

Tags: python, kivymd

I'm learning `kivymd` and I would like to create a `MDList` with an `OneLineAvatarIconListItem` that has two left icons. The [docs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/list/#custom-list-item) only show how to do that with two right icons.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch

KV = '''
OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
    text: "One-line item with avatar"
    on_size:
        self.ids._left_container.width = container.width
        self.ids._left_container.x = container.width

    YourContainer:
        id: container

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "minus"

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "plus"

    IconRightWidget:
        icon: "cog"
'''


class YourContainer(ILeftBodyTouch, MDBoxLayout):
    adaptive_width = True


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

If I change "right" by "left" everywhere, the icons are misplaced:
[image: picture1]

I guess I have to do something more...

Answer (score -1):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch

KV = """
OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
    text: "One-line item with avatar"
    on_size:
        self.ids._left_container.width = container.width
        self.ids._left_container.x = container.width
        self._txt_left_pad = dp(100)  # increase pad to make room
       
    IconRightWidget:
        icon: "cog"

    YourContainer:
        id: container
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.minimum_width  # size the BoxLayout

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "minus"

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "plus"
"""

class YourContainer(ILeftBodyTouch, MDBoxLayout):
    adaptive_width = True

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Example().run()
```

[OneLineAvatarIconListItem with two icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7q9U.png)

https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/-kZnhU1HQHc